# Sending message from one terminal user to another user

Tags: terminal, tty, write

I have a user of name x in tty1 and y in tty2. Now x wants to write some message to y and vice-versa.
Now I typed in tty1 terminal `write y tty2`
It is showing

write:write:you have write permission turned off

write:y has messages disabled

Same thing is showing when y's sending message to x instead it is 'x' in the last line.
What should I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that `y` has turned off messages.

In `y`'s terminal, type:

```
$ mesg
is n
```

meaning `y` does not allow others to write to `y`'s terminal. Then you should try:

```
$ mesg y
```

**Note**

This option **y** in above command is different with `y` user in your case.

From `man mesg`:

```
NAME
       mesg - control write access to your terminal

SYNOPSIS
       mesg [y|n]

DESCRIPTION
       Mesg  controls the access to your terminal by others.  It's typically used to allow or disallow other users to write to your terminal
       (see write(1)).

OPTIONS
       y      Allow write access to your terminal.

       n      Disallow write access to your terminal.

       If no option is given, mesg prints out the current access state of your terminal.
```

Comment: It is showing Usage:mesg[y|n] and the prompt is coming then.

Comment: @saptarshinag: you must type `mesg y <enter>`. `y` is an option of `mesg`, not your user.

Comment: Oh i see,sorry for my mistake

Comment: It works! but after logout and again logging in one of the terminal the first message is still showing,i.e,write:write:you have write permission turned off...it is working though.Thanks!

Comment: @saptarshinag: Becasue in your system, message is not turn on by default. What is your OS?

Comment: It's ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @saptarshinag: You should edit `/etc/default/devpts` to make it default.

Comment: I've opened the file.What edit shall I do here?

Comment: Look at the comment: `# Set to 600 to have 'mesg n' be the default`

Comment: Yes.So should I make it 'mesg y'?

Comment: @saptarshinag: change `TTYMODE` to `620` to make it enable by default.

Comment: However TTYMODE is already 620 here.

Comment: @saptarshinag: It's strange. Can you write message by default now?

Comment: No the problem persists. :(

Comment: @saptarshinag: You should ask another question for this problem, so other people can help you. I'm doing some research on it.

Comment: ok for your convenience the content of the file is        # GID of the `tty' group
TTYGRP=5

# Set to 600 to have `mesg n' be the default
TTYMODE=620

Answer (score 3):

If X is the usr who wants to pop a message on y machine. Fisrt take the terminal id  of y machine and both should be on the same host. you can send a message like below.

1. Type `who` command and see the terminal id of y machine( for example `pty/1` is the terminal ID of y)
2. `echo "Hello" 1> pty/1`(this will display the message on y machine.

Comment: Y had to set the full path: `echo "Hi" 1> /dev/pts/1`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do anything (unless you are the root user).

Each user can enable/disable other users ability to send messages to them using the command mesg.  This command can be put into your .bashrc or .login file (depending on shell).

The default if you do nothing is to protect the user from these interrupting messages from other users.

Answer (score 0):

```
> $ who
bouba    :0           2015-07-30 07:10 (:0)
jdone    pts/1        2015-07-30 20:07
bouba    pts/12       2015-07-30 20:39 (:0)
> $ mesg y
> $ write jdone
```

jdone its your userName
and here type your message
and press Entre To send